# print function '@#%' python

Tags: python, function, printing

how can I print this "drawing" without losing formatting?

```
@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.                   .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.       
@@   /         @@@@@@@@                 .                 @@@@@@@@@            /
@@    @@@@@*              ,@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                .@@@@    @
@@@   %@@@@@@@@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#     &@@@@@@@@@    @
@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@
@@@/   &@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@
@@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@@
@@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@@
@@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&    @@@
@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@
@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @
@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@(  @@@@@@@@@@@@@*     @@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      @@@@(  @@@@@@@@@@@@@      &@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.   .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%   .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   
@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@              @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    
@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @
@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@  ,@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@, @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@
@@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@  &@  ,@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@@
@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@  .@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    /@@@@
@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@    @@@@#    (@@&    @@@@/   #@@@@@@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#     @@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@.     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#     #@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@&      .@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        ,@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@         @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%               ..,..               @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                     @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I'd like to print some of these 'drawings'

I tried `print(f'')` but it also didn't work

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.  Even before that, you have to clearly specify your problem.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Use triple quotes.

```
print('''hello
there
person''')
```

**output**

```
hello
there
person
```

Implementing this I got a correctly formatted cat.